# QA/Staging envirnoment for wordpress sites

Tags: themes, content, staging

I have different wordpress environments as Local, Staging, Live. I start writing contents with Local, then push to Staging and once Tested on staging need to push to live server

1. I know that I can use export/import pages/posts. what is the best practice to do this without loosing any internal resources like images/js files/css etc
2. If I am customising the themes, do I need to make the same customizations in different environmets or export and import themes ?

Comment: best practices are subjective and vary based on your specific situation. please try to be more specific. In addition those kinds of work flows were described already on the web, please do some research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dev.example.com, so that you dont have to move contents all the time.

you can make it password and ip protected if you want